# Anyone know why sagemaker would not be able to reach the files.fast.ai server

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, fast-ai

I have setup fast.ai sagemaker jupyter notebooks. The notebook environment works fine however its not able to download files from files.fast.ai server. Its able to reach fast.ai server. (attach pings from terminal)

Anyone have a clue?

[image: not able to reach files.fast.ai server]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow lifecycle config steps mentioned in this doc https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/running-fast-ai-notebooks-with-amazon-sagemaker/?

I was able to `!wget "http://files.fast.ai/data/examples/adult_sample.tgz"` successfully after setting the lifecycle config mentioned in the doc above.

[image]